# jQuery draggable clone with y axis restriction

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

If I have this markup:

```
<table id="sometable">
      <tr>
          <td class="x"><span>111</span></td>
          <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="x"><span>222</span></td>
          <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>       
</table>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$(".x span").draggable({ helper: 'clone', axis: 'y'});
```

When dragging the first column the cloned span is snapping to the second column rather than the first column. If I try to drag the table cell rather than the span inside it snaps outside of the table. If I remove axis:'y' is works as expected except I no longer have the Y axis restriction that I would like. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a containment & snap.

```
$(".x span").draggable({ 
    snap: '.x', 
    snapMode: 'inner', 
    containment: '#sometable', 
    helper: 'clone', 
    axis: 'y'
});
```

Comment: In my code I am actually specifying the containment; in this case I would set it to '#sometable', '.x' wouldn't allow me to drag it outside of the cell. With or without the containment specified it does the same thing :(

Comment: Do you have a droppable set up as well?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm planning on adding one as soon as I make the draggable work properly.

Comment: You're correct about the containment needing to be the table. You need that droppable though. That's what will allow you to drag between the .x td's. 

You may want to specify a snap and/or grid.

`$(".x span").draggable({ snap: '.x', snapMode: 'inner', containment: '.x', helper: 'clone', axis: 'y'});`